# What determines which class definition is included for identically-named classes in two source files?

Tags: c++, templates

If I have two source files in a project that each define a class of the same name, what determines which version of the class is used?

For example:

```
// file1.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "file2.h"

struct A
{
    A() : a(1) {}
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    // foo() <-- uncomment this line to draw in file2.cpp's use of class A

    A a; // <-- Which version of class A is chosen by the linker?
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl; // <-- Is "1" or "2" output?
}
```

...

```
//file2.h:

void foo();
```

...

```
// file2.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "file2.h"

struct A
{
    A() : a(2) {}
    int a;
};

void foo()
{
    A a; // <-- Which version of class A is chosen by the linker?
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl; // <-- Is "1" or "2" output?
}
```

I have been able to get different versions of `A` to be selected by the linker, with identical code - merely by changing the order in which I type the code (building along the way).

Granted, it's poor programming practice to include different definitions of classes in the same namespace with the same name.  However, are there defined rules that determine which class will be selected by the linker - and if so, what are they?

As a useful addendum to this question, I would like to know (in general) how the compiler / linker handles classes - does the compiler, when it builds each source file, incorporate the class name and compiled class definition within the object file, whereas the linker (in the scenario of a name clash) throws away one set of compiled class function/member definitions?

The issue of a name clash is not arcane - I now realize that it happens EVERY TIME a header-only template file is `#included` by two or more source files (and subsequently the same template classes are instantiated, and the same member functions called, in these multiple source files), as is a common scenario with the STL.  Each source file must have a separately-compiled version of the same instantiated template class functions, so the linker MUST be selecting among different such compiled versions of these functions at linkage time), I would think.

-- ADDENDUM with related question about Java --

I note that various answers have indicated the One Definition Rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule) for C++.  As an interesting aside, am I correct that Java has NO SUCH rule - so that multiple, different definitions ARE allowed in Java by the Java specifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a C++ program provides two definitions of the same class (i.e., within the same namespace and named identical), the program violates the rules of the standard and you'll get undefined behavior. What exactly does happen somewhat depends on the compiler and linker: sometimes you get a linker error but this isn't required.

The obvious fix is not to have conflicting class names. The easiest approach to obtain unique class names is to define locally used types within an unnamed namespace:

```
// file1.cpp
namespace {
    class A { /*...*/ };
}

// file2.cpp
namespace {
    class A { /*...*/ };
}
```

These two classes won't conflict.

Comment: Does the standard, in fact, say that a program is not allowed to provide different definitions of the same class?  It strikes me that the standard could not say this, because it would be impossible to enforce - for example, if one of two source files is later modified and the program rebuilt, but a compiled object file for the second source file that was built previously, with a previous version of the compiler, is linked.  Therefore, perhaps it is not stated in the standard that differing class definitions are forbidden?  This seems like a difficult grey area.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: There is no ambiguity! The standard states the one definition rule explicitly: 3.2 [basic.def.odr] paragraph 6. It is too long to be quoted in a comment, though. The whole point of this definition is that the compiler and/or linker may not be able to check that the constraint is obeyed. Thus, the program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Such a program violates the One Definition Rule and exhibits undefined behavior.

If there are multiple definitions of a class or inline function in a program (in different translation units, or source files), then all of the definitions must be identical.  Neither the compiler nor the linker is required to diagnose all violations of this rule (and not all violations can be easily diagnosed).

Answer (score 2):

This is only successfully linking because the definitions for the 2 constructors are implied to be `inline`.  Try moving them under the class and not using the `inline` keyword. The kind of linkage you are abusing tells the linker that there will be multiple definitions, where normally it would error that you're breaking the One Definition Rule, which you are actually breaking. Normally this condition that allows you to seemingly break ODR exists for things like templates, which will always have multiple identical definitions in different translation units. But that's the condition: definitions in different translation units must be identical.

Ultimately it's up to your compiler which gets used, in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will give you a warning for multiple definitions if you allow it (which you should).

The gnu linker resolves symbols in the order that you present files on the command line, so it uses the first definition that it sees.  Not sure if all linkers work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule) exists is so that it doesn't matter which definition is used, they're all identical. It's completely up to the compiler and linker in question as to which version is used, or whether they're consistent. The only externally viewable side effect is when there's a static variable inside a function, a single instance of the variable must be used between all instatiations of the function.

By violating the One Definition Rule you're exposing the mechanics of the compiler/linker in a way that isn't relevant to a correctly written program.