# Despite violation of the One Definition Rule, how is it possible that a compiler/linker COULD choose an alternate inline constructor?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker

Referring to [What determines which class definition is included for identically-named classes in two source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388536/what-determines-which-class-definition-is-included-for-identically-named-classes), in which there is a deliberate, clear violation of the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule), I am still confused how it is even POSSIBLE for the compiler/linker to have the option of selecting one definition over another.

(ADDENDUM based on answers/comments: I am looking for a single example of how a compiler/linker *could* produce the result indicated below, given code that is deliberately in violation of the standard and that therefore the code results in undefined behavior.)

The code sample is:

```
// file1.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "file2.h"

struct A
{
    A() : a(1) {}
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    // foo() <-- uncomment this line to draw in file2.cpp's use of class A

    A a; // <-- Which version of class A is chosen by the linker?
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl; // <-- Is "1" or "2" output?
}
```

...

```
//file2.h:

void foo();
```

...

```
// file2.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "file2.h"

struct A
{
    A() : a(2) {}
    int a;
};

void foo()
{
    A a; // <-- Which version of class A is chosen by the linker?
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl; // <-- Is "1" or "2" output?
}
```

In this case, the function `foo()` sometimes prints 1, and sometimes 2.

But the constructor for `A` is inline!  It's not a function call!  Therefore, I would think that the *compiler* must include the assembly/machine instructions for the code that instantiates the object `a` within the compiled code for function `foo()` itself at the time that the function `foo()` is compiled.

Therefore, I would think that *later*, at linking time, the linker will NOT change the assembly/machine instructions for the definition of `foo()` when it decides to include the function `foo()` in the compiled binary (since it's only known that `foo()` is, in fact, being called, at linking time).  According to this reasoning, the linker could not possibly influence which inline constructor code is compiled into the function `foo()`, so it must be file2's version of the inline constructor that is always used, despite the deliberate violation of the One Definition Rule.

If the constructor for `A` were NOT inline, then I would understand that when the function `foo()` is compiled, a JUMP statement to a function (the constructor for `A`) might be placed inside the assembled code for the function `foo()`; then, later, at linkage time, the linker could then fill in the address of the JUMP statement with its choice of the two definitions of the constructor for `A`.

The only explanation I can think of for the fact that in reality, sometime `foo()` prints `1` and sometimes `foo()` prints `2` despite the presence of the inline constructor is that the compiler, when it compiles "file2.cpp", creates SPACE in the compiled assembly/machine code representing the function `foo()` for the inline call to the constructor for A, but does not actually fill in the assembly/machine code itself; and that later, at linkage time, the linker copies the code for the constructor for `A` into the pre-determined location within the compiled definition of the function `foo()` itself, using its (arbitrary) choice between the two definitions of the inline function for the constructor for `A`.

Is my explanation correct, or is there another explanation?  How is it possible, in this example, despite the deliberate violation of the One Definition Rule, for the compiler/linker to have a choice in which constructor for `A` is called, given that the constructor call is inline?

**ADDENDUM: I changed the title and added a paragraph of clarification near the top, in response to comments and answers, to make it clear that I understand that the behavior is undefined in this example, and that I am looking for a single example of how a real compiler/linker *could* produce the observed behavior even once.  Note that I'm not looking for an answer that predicts what the behavior will be at any particular time.**

**ADDENDUM 2**: In response to a comment, I have placed a breakpoint at the line `A a;` in the VS debugger and selected the "disassembly" view.  Indeed, it is plain as day from the disassembly code that DESPITE the presence of "inline", in this case the compiler has chosen NOT to inline the constructor call for the object `a`:

[image: Disassembly view of the line `A a; from the code sample in the question: The compiler has chosen not to inline the constructor call, despite its being inline.]

Therefore, Alf's answer is correct: Despite the implicit `inline` of the constructor, the constructor call has NOT been inlined.

A tangential question therefore arises: Can a clear-cut statement be made - one way or the other - regarding whether constructors are less likely to be inlined than regular member functions (assuming `inline` is present, either explicitly or implicitly, in both cases)?  If a statement *can* be made about this and the answer is "yes, the compiler is more likely to reject `inline` for a constructor, than it is to reject `inline` for a regular member function", then a follow-up question would be "why"?

Comment: Maybe it's just an undefined behaviour?

Comment: @hate-engine That's the entire point of my question - how is it possible for there to be undefined behavior in this particular example?  If I understood how it's possible for there to be undefined behavior, then I'd have the answer to the question.

Comment: There is no explanation, anything can happen when you violate the rules. Not limited to the compiler inlining either constructor based on some random bits in memory.

Comment: Violating the ODR results in undefined behaviour, which, by definition, can do anything, something, nothing at all and all of the above at the same time.

Comment: I am asking for somebody who understands the way compilers and linkers work to explain how undefined behavior is possible in *this particular example*.  I already understand that the ODR has been violated and therefore I should not be *surprised* by undefined behavior, but that is *not my question*.

Comment: Simple: The C++ Standard said "It's undefined behaviour". That's how it's possible.

Comment: @Dan: The standard clearly states that you get UB as soon as you violate the ODR. This has nothing to do with compilers or linkers, the UB *is just there*.

Comment: @Xeo - I do not agree.  Compilers and linkers aren't phantoms; they're programs.  I am looking for an explanation of how it is *possible* for undefined behavior in this particular example.  An example of how a compiler and/or linker could be causing the behavior I *actually see* - that is my question.  Simply stating "don't expect any particular behavior" is already a given.

Comment: Aren't you already getting "behaviour you actually see"? You said you sometimes get `1` and sometimes `2`, that's the essence of UB.

Comment: I also disagree it is UB - it is because of [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: @Xeo - You may not understand how a specific implementation of a compiler/linker results in the observed behavior (given that the standard does not define what should happen) - I am looking for a specific example of how a choice of implementation for a compiler/linker could result in the behavior I observe.  I already understand that the result is undefined.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum you'd have to look at the implementation of that specific compiler to understand that.

Comment: @TonyTheLion My question is for somebody who already understands compilers/linkers sufficiently to answer my question, so that I don't have to look at a compiler implementation.

Comment: There is no such thing, because each individual compiler implementation will behave in different ways depending on the exact details. The only way to know for certain would be to debug MSVC's source code, for example.

Comment: @DeadMG I would like to know one *example* of how a compiler/linker *even once* might produce the result I see.  I'm not looking for an explanation for how to predict what will happen at any given time.

Comment: @DeadMG: Most linkers work in much the same way; you only need a general understanding of that process, not detailed knowledge of any particular implementation, to give a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Defining your constructor in the class definition is equivalent to using the keyword `inline` and an out-of-class defintion of it.

`inline` does not require/guarantee inline expansion of machine code. It hints about that, but that's all.

The guaranteed effect of `inline` is to allow the same definition of the function in multiple translation units (it must then be defined, essentially identically, in all translation units where it's used).

Thus, your logic based on assumption of required/guaranteed inline expansion of calls, yields incorrect conclusions due to incorrect assumption.

Comment: I have appended to my question a screenshot of the disassembly for one particular build of this code from Visual Studio 2010.  The disassembly makes clear that in the particular instance I've captured of the built code, the constructor is *not* being inlined - your answer is right on the money.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I know this is an old thread, but I just stumbled uon it and was wondering if your test/screenshot were done when compiling with Debug or Release settings? Because I am pretty sure that VS, when using Debug configuration, does not inline *any* functions

Comment: @baruch This was almost certainly a debug build.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really surprised that the code may ever link. I'm almost sure it doesn't link with MS Visual Studio, with the linker complaining about names colliding.

In such cases, you could use anonymous namespaces for the definition of your structs if you really don't want to give them different names.

Comment: The code links and runs, as is (both with `foo()` present, and with it commented out) in VS 2010.

Comment: Also note that I am not asking how to resolve the problem; I can easily resolve it.  This is a deliberate case where I am evaluating undefined behavior.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means that the behaviour is **not defined**, as in, **any behaviour** is as acceptable as is nothing at all. So, evaluating UB is pointless, cause really, anything could happen.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: as a practical matter, it can help save much time to *understand* what's going on. both for avoiding UB unpleasantness in the first place, and for identifying UB and getting things fixed.

Comment: @Tony: it's not pointless at all. Once you work out why you get the behavior you observe, you learn something about your implementation. What you don't learn about, is the standard, because "it's UB" is everything the standard says on the matter.

Comment: To understand what's going on then  you'd have to look at the specific implementation.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I get paid for writing code that works. Spending time figuring out what the compiler actually did when I wrote nonsense code doesn't produce code that works. So, for example, I don't care a whit what code the compiler generates for `i = i++1;` because it's not code that works. YMMV.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: yes. and also the standard. it's a combined effect, since the implementation strives to implement the standard. it's good to learn about both. and know which is which. :-)

Comment: @TonyTheLion and PeteBecker - you may not care about the answer to the question, in which case, you're free not to answer.  My years of writing C++ code professionally has led me to simply *wonder* how the behavior I observe is even possible, *given* that anything can happen because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum maybe you could look at the assembly generated code, you would see what is compiled and what it does

Comment: @PeteBecker: indeed, my mileage does vary. As well as getting paid to write code that works, I also get paid to observe code that doesn't work, and determine what is wrong with it. I have in the past occasionally been paid to muck about with compilers. So I simply cannot accept this claim that knowing how C++ implementations work is worthless.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I don't see how spending time figuring out what the compiler did with an ODR violation helps in identifying and removing the ODR violation.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am not asking about how to identify and remove the ODR violation.  I placed it in this code sample deliberately.  I would like someone who understands compiler and/or linker implementations, as well as C++, to answer the question I asked.

Comment: @PeteBecker: well, I'm not debugging this case in particular so I can't say exactly whether it would help or not. But the argument that knowledge of implementation details of UB is worthless was made in general. And in general, knowing what the implementation does with particular classes of UB often helps direct attention to where the problem lies. Of course sometimes it fails, because likely the user doesn't know *every* detail of the implementation. It's merely a valuable heuristic.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum - in my answer I described what might be happening. Beyond that, there's really nothing to say.

Comment: @PeteBecker - your answer does not describe what might be happening.  You say that the linker isn't involved; then you proceed to say that the chances are it will compile and build, and that it will 'do what it looks like it should do'.  I don't see how that is a description of what might be happening?  Also, how do you know what it *should* be doing, since the behavior is undefined?  Finally, I think your answer is incorrect, as Alf's answer indicates: you say that the linker isn't involved, but in that answer he makes it clear that the linker COULD be involved, which answers my question.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I have taken your suggestion and looked at the disassembly.  I have attached a screenshot of the disassembly at the bottom of my question.  In fact, from the disassembly, the compiler has chosen to disregard the implicit `inline` for the constructor, which answers my question.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum thanx for the added report. (I had already +1  your question).

Answer (score 0):

Violations of the ODR do not require diagnostics. That is, if you do it, the behavior of your program is undefined: anything can happen. In the example, the linker probably isn't involved, because all of the member functions are inline, so chances are the code will compile and link without complaint, and do what it looks like it should do. Nevertheless, the standard doesn't promise that that will happen; that's what undefined behavior means.

Comment: It appears your answer is wrong.  The linker could be involved.  See Alf's answer.

Comment: Your amended question asks how a compiler/linker **could** produce this result. The mechanism I described is, indeed, how a compiler/linker **could** produce this result. Why do you say it can't possibly be that? (Note that I amended my answer by adding "probably"; if that's the problem you see, it's been fixed)

Comment: How is "anything can happen" an explanation?  Alf's answer *is* an explanation: The compiler *might not* inline the code, leaving it up to the linker - in other words, the answer is exactly the scenario in which the "probably" you've just included does *not* apply.  I appreciate your fixing the answer to include "probably".

Comment: @DanNissenbaum - it's not. Read the next sentence.

Comment: From the next sentence: "chances are the code will compile and link without complaint, and do what it looks like it should do".  How is that an explanation?  Or is it the first half of the sentence that you believe provides an explanation?

Comment: Pete - I've added a screenshot to my question that shows the interesting result that the Visual Studio compiler has chosen not to inline the call to the constructor, despite the presence of the implicit `inline`.  The answer to my question is therefore clear: The linker **is** sometimes involved, and in such cases, at linking time, the linker has its choice of either version of the constructor.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum - adding new information that makes you think you know what's happening does not invalidate answers to your original question, which asked (several times) for **possible** mechanisms.

Comment: Pete - as I've noted, your answer does not provide *any* possibly mechanism.  Alf's answer, and the disassembly I've attached, does provide an explanation.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum - you've misquoted me twice, and now you insist that black is white. Three strikes and you're out. Clearly, intellectual honesty is not a part of your world.

Comment: Pete - No ill will - Your answer is right up there for everybody to see.  How could I misquote it?   I'm just trying to get my question answered, that is all - I don't believe that's intellectually dishonest.  Please quote, from your answer, where you describe a mechanism that could explain the behavior I described in my question.  If I missed something in your answer, I will stand corrected.